# Simple Hello World NodeACS Server issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, jenkins, titanium

I am trying to make a simple NodeACS app in which I want to receive some data in xml format as request from cURL and in Node ACS app after receiving that data I want to send response to client.

**My system configurations are:**

**Node**  *v0.10.13 (x86)*

**Titanium SDK version:**  *Titanium Studio, build: 3.4.0.201409261227 Build: jenkins-titanium-rcp-master-197 (origin/master)*

**OS** : *Windows 7 64 bit*

Following is my code files:

**application.js:**

```
function index(req, res) {
    console.log(req.headers);
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("Data received successfully");
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
    });
}
```

**config.json:**

```
{
  "routes":
  [
    { "path": "/", "method":"POST", "callback": "application#index" }
  ],
  "filters":
  [
     { "path": "/", "callback": "" }
  ],
  "websockets":
  [
    { "event": "", "callback": ""}
  ]
}
```

I'm running my code from command prompt as: 
`acs run --port 7788`

There are no changes made by me in any other file. The issue is when I'm trying to POST XML data via curl using following command :

`curl -X POST -d @output.xml http://localhost:7788/`

then only headers is getting printed in console as:

```
D:\GMON-Server\GMON-Server>acs run --port 7788
ACS: Appcelerator Cloud Services Command-Line Interface, version 1.0.20
Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

[INFO]  No dependencies detected
[INFO]  socket.io started
[INFO]  ACS started on port 7788
[INFO]  { 'user-agent': 'curl/7.39.0',
  host: 'localhost:7788',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-length': '55580',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  expect: '100-continue' }
```

and neither the ***req.on('data')*** event nor the ***req.on('end')*** event is firing.

Please tell me whether there is any configuration issue or there is something wrong with my code?